# Background doesn't change

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

Good day.

**HTML**

```
<div id="Button"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
background: url("../images/play.png") left center no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#Button").on("click",function() {
  $(this).css("background", 'url("../images/pause.png") left center no-repeat;');
});
```

But unfortunately, the background doesn't change. Why doesnt it?

Comment: There's no obvious error. Please make a demo in what environment you are using this (when are you calling the snippet, how does the DOM look).

Comment: maybe [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as \`getElementById\` not find the element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)?

Comment: Your issue is likely related to the structure of your file system. The path `../images/` is relative to the context in which it's being executed, which depending on where your CSS and JS reside, may be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is with the semicolumn in the end of the property value. remove it and try.

EX:

```
$(this).css("background", 'url("http://placehold.it/32x32") left center no-repeat');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eQ4WD/)**

presence of semi-column while specifying the value for the css property name makes it invalid and it doesn't get applied.

```
 $(this).css("background", 'url("../images/pause.png") left center no-repeat;');
                                                                            ^___ Here
```

*Also do note that applying css directly to the element makes it more difficult for cascading the styles and less maintainable, since they are applied directly on to the style property of the element. Best way to go is to add a css rule and set the class to the element.*

Comment: yes, thanks for help, i dont know that symbol **;** not need write... +1)

Answer (score 1):

This is more efficient way and you seperate your code

**HTML**

```
<div id="Button"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
background: url("../images/play.png") left center no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
```

div with Class bg

div.bg {

```
background: url("../images/pause.png") left center no-repeat;
```

}

**JQuery**

```
$("#Button").on("click",function() {
  $(this).addClass("bg");
});
```

Comment: thanks. good answer but i want know where error in my code. thanks for answer. +1)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set each property separately.
Also you should check that url is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#Button").on("click", function () {
    $(this).css({
        'background-image': 'url("../images/pause.png")', 
        'background-position': 'left center', 
        'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'
    });
});
```

As Bergi and André Dion mentioned in the comments, you can remove the `background-position` and `background-repeat` properties if they don't need to change when the background image does.

Comment: You can omit the latter two since they don't differ from the initial CSS values.

Comment: You don't need to re-set the `background-position` and `background-repeat` properties if they aren't changing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may have been incorrect image paths or the semicolon in the css (adding a semicolon will make it not work). I have created a jsfiddle the demonstrates the solution to your problem, although with alternate images since I don't have access to your originals.

http://jsfiddle.net/VpWcB/

The relevant js code is reproduced below:

```
$("#Button").on("click", function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'url(../images/pause.png) left center no-repeat');
})
```

Comment: How is your solution different than the OP's? What is invalid about his CSS?

Comment: I think it was pretty clear in my answer - the semicolon was incorrect, and the image path may have been incorrect (but I can't be sure). In addition, I have an example of the code here working linked in a jsfiddle. I think it may be a little harsh to downvote a correct answer with a working example @AndréDion - please don't be a troll.

Comment: Downvotes are a part of SO and are a way to measure the quality of content—get used to it. Your original answer didn't mention anything about a semi-colon—it simply stated that his CSS was invalid.

Comment: I understand this, but I am more used to downvotes being used on low quality content as you mentioned, not content that correctly answers posted questions, explains possible reasons why, and provides functional examples of the solution, as this answer does.